# Git: how to untrack files without staging them for deletion

Tags: git, git-reset, git-rm, git-stage, git-track

I have some config files that I want to change locally but not risk accidentally committing those changes. They also cannot be added to gitignore because they need to be tracked for the project as a whole. When I modify those files to suit my environment's needs, my `git status` looks like this:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   config1.cfg
        modified:   config2.cfg

Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        whatever.html
        somethingElse.js
```

then I run:

```
git rm --cached config1.cfg config2.cfg
```

and `git status` looks like this:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    config1.cfg
        deleted:    config2.cfg

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    config1.cfg
    config2.cfg
    whatever.html
    somethingElse.js
```

Running `git reset --HEAD config1.cfg config2.cfg` returns them to the staging area, predictably. But it kind of doesn't make sense that something could be untracked and still staged at the same time, even if that staging is for deletion. But also -- I didn't delete the files, but if I commit now then they will be deleted.

I realize that this might be a better use case for smudge and clean filters, but is it possible to reach a state where a previously tracked file is untracked and it is as if it has never been tracked? If not, is there a good reason it isn't possible?

Editing to clarify now that I understand the situation a little better: the scenario I'm trying to create is one where the files are untracked on my local while I'm working, without affecting their tracking status on the remote.

Comment: You are doing `git rm` but you do not want them to be removed from the repository?

Comment: Really the scenario I want is for them to be untracked only on my local while I'm working, without that affecting origin at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if I commit now then they will be deleted.

No. The *files* (the things you see in front of you in the work tree) will not be deleted. Committing has *no effect* on the work tree.

The *commit* will record them as deleted, as it must do, because they were present in the previous commit and now you are saying they should not be present in this next commit. That is what a deletion is: something that was present is now no longer present.

### The Three Places of Git

It sounds like you might benefit from knowing a bit about what Git "is". Git exercises sway over three places:

- The **work tree**. This is what Git shows you. It is a rendering of a folder full of files onto disk so that you can edit those files.
- The **index**. Also called the staging area or cache. This is an invisible collection of *references* to files that constructs what your next commit will consist of.
- The actual **repository**. An invisible collection of *commits*. The commits themselves each contain files, in a certain sense of the word "contain" whose details are not important here.

When you check out a branch, you are checking out a commit. The commit is used to populate the work tree and the index; they all match up at that moment.

If you change one file in the work tree (which is the only place where you *can* change anything) and add it and commit, then only that one file changed, true, but all the other files are still there in the work tree and the index, so this commit contains *all the files* — not just the file that you changed (that is a common misconception). Every commit is a snapshot of the *whole* state of the index at the time it was created, which in turn is a reflection of the *whole* state of the work tree, mediated by what you have elected to add to the index.

So the index is the place where you get to manipulate the relationship between what you did in the work tree and what will go into the next commit. When you say `git add .`, you are saying, in effect, "the index should reflect *everything* I did in the work tree". But that is a very broad command; you have absolute file-by-file fine control of what the index should look like in the run-up to the next commit.

### What You Did

When you said `git rm --cached config1.cfg`, you said, "Remove the *reference* to *config1.cfg* from the *index*." This will have no effect on the work tree when you commit; it will just make a commit in which *config1.cfg* happens to be absent.

But now you are thinking about that, and you are realizing that isn't what you meant to say, because the next commit will constitute a *deletion* of *config1.cfg*. You don't like that. You *do* want the next commit to still contain *config1.cfg*; you just don't want it to be *changed* from the previous commit.

That, I take it, is what you mean when you say:

> I have some config files that I want to change locally but not risk accidentally committing those changes

### What You Should Have Done

Your goal was not to make a commit in which *config1.cfg* was not present. Your goal was to make a commit in which *config1.cfg* was *unchanged* from its previous state, even though you have in fact edited it in the work tree.

Okay, so what should you have done in order to make that happen? Well, the first line of defense is: don't say `git add .` or some blanket globbing statement like that. Instead, in order to *not* add changed files to the index, *don't add them*. Just add to the index the changed files that you *do* want to reflect in the next commit.

But let's say you recklessly blew past that safeguard and you *did* add *config1.cfg* in its changed state to the index. (You did.) Then say `git restore --staged config1.cfg`. This copies *config1.cfg* out of the last commit (every commit contains all the files, remember?) into the index. So now the *config1.cfg* in the index looks like the previous commit, not like the work tree version. The status will be then that git knows you have modified *config1.cfg* in the work tree (unless you have added it to the gitignores file), but that change is *not* slated to be included in the next commit you make.

(Before Git version 2.25.0, you would have used a form of `git reset` to accomplish this goal, namely `git reset config1.cfg`. But `git reset` is scary, so if you have a sufficiently new Git, use `restore` instead.)

Comment: Hm yeah that is an important semantical distinction. Not intuitive but makes sense in terms of what git is really about.

But does this mean that if I push my branch it won't actually remove those files from the repository on the origin?

Comment: Again, it's about commits, not files. Of course if you push a commit that lacks this file on your machine, that commit will lack the file on the remote machine, because it is the very same commit. Git would not be much use if pushing or pulling a commit did not copy it identically.

Comment: Expanded my answer to try to come closer to the general sense of what you actually asked.

Comment: @AndrewToups: removing the files from some *commit* **never** removes them from the *repository*. The repository is a collection of commits; none of the commits that are in it ever change; you add *new* commits to the repository, which means the repository only ever grows. (There are some special cases where this isn't true but that's the general idea.) But the new commit says "don't have these files", so when you extract that commit, you won't have those files. The old commit that says "have these files" will give you those files when you extract it.

Comment: Where I'm still confused is that the remote machine has those files in its repository. Untracking them doesn't delete them from the filesystem on my local, but if it's merged with origin/master, it effectively will remove them from the repository there, which would still wreak havoc on anyone who needs to use it. Is that correct?

Comment: Also just want to say I'm grateful for these clear and insightful responses and I'm sorry that I'm being a little dense about it. Just hard to wrap my head around.

Comment: @matt Looking at your edits -- I really appreciate this thorough explanation. For what it's worth, I do use `git add -p`/`-i` to make sure that I don't accidentally stage those changes. But the bigger issue is that I still have to manually manage these changes every time I pull from the remote on master, and worse, the environment I'm working on mysteriously breaks when trying to apply the local config changes from `git stash` or even another local branch dedicated to those changes. Just looking for a more "set it and forget" solution that requires less micromanagement and error potential.

Comment: And that may not exist and that's fine if it doesn't, I'm very grateful to have deepened my understanding of git from these responses.

Comment: Well obviously you could try to configure the index to disregard changes that you make in these files; that is what `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is for. But in general the problem of mutable configuration files is a very, very standard git problem and has been discussed here many times; there is little need for us to go over this ground once again.

Comment: @matt I appreciate the lengths to which you have gone. It might be good to add `git update-index --assume-unchanged` as a suggestion to your original answer as I feel that most directly addresses the root problem of my question. I couldn't find any other relevant issues on stackoverflow when I posted this but that was clearly a case of not knowing the right question to ask.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to add `assume-unchanged` to my answer because I don't recommend it. It doesn't solve the problem so much as it expresses desperation at the fact that there _is_ a problem. The git documentation itself recommends against solving the problem that way: "In general, Git does not provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files... If the file you want to change is some sort of config file, the repository can include a sample config file that can then be copied into the ignored name and modified."

Comment: @matt Yeah that would be ideal but just isn't the case with this project. Not git's fault though!

Answer (score 0):

## **Untrack changes from the staging phase:**

If you have happened to stage files using `git add [fileName]` and you want to untrack them from the stage, you can use the following command:

`git rm -r --cached [fileName]`

If you want to untrack ***all the files in the stage***, you can use the below command:

`git rm -r --cached .`

Comment: This is what he did, isn’t it? Was the question, kind of. And: There already is an excellent answer — which value exactly did you add?